# Adding element to an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I've got an array of strings

```
char **tab;
```

and I want it to be able to increase as user types in new strings. I've created this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **tab=malloc(sizeof(char*));
    tab[0]=malloc(41*sizeof(char));
    int i=0;
    int d=0;
    while(strcmp(tab[i],"END"))
    {
        if(d==0)
        {
            i--;
            d++;
        }
        i++;
        scanf("%s",tab[i]);
        **tab=realloc(tab,(i+2)*sizeof(char*));
        tab[i+1]=malloc(41*sizeof(char));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

its purpose is to read new strings to tab untill user writes keyword "END". Since it's not known how many words will be inputted I tried to reallocate the size of array after each iteration. Unfortunately it prints Segmentation fault after getting 3 words.
What did i do wrong? Is there any better way to do this task?

Maximum length of any word is 40

Comment: `tab=realloc(tab,` ...

Comment: in the loop body, `**tab=...` ===> `tab = ...`. Unrelated, this algorithm is inefficient, and more important, broken if you expect *no* allocations in the event the first string entered is `"END"`. Just saying.

Comment: It worked! Thank You. I can't even tell how dumb I feel right now

Comment: Here `while(strcmp(tab[i],"END"))` the string variable pointed to by `tab[i]` is uninitialized. You could consider `calloc` instead of `malloc`

Comment: You don't need the `if(d==0) { … }` part. Just move the `i++` just below `scanf("%s",tab[i]);`

Comment: Start with a reasonable number of pointers allocated. Keep a counter for the number allocated and the number used. When `used == allocated`, then `realloc` instead of every iteration. Never `realloc` the pointer itself. `realloc` can fail and return `NULL` overwriting your current `tab` creating a memory leak. Instead use temp pointer, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc (tab, ...);` and validate `if (!tmp) { /* handle error */ } tab = tmp;`

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is broken in two significant places

- `**tab = ...` in the loop body is wrong. If `tab` is `char**`, then `*tab` would be `char*`, and `**tab` would be `char`. Assigning a memory address to `char` should flag huge warnings from your toolchain, and if it doesn't either turn up your warning levels or get a new toolchain.
- Initial entry to your while condition evaluates *indeterminate* data. At that time you have allocated raw memory for `tab[0]`, but nothing has populated it yet. Therefore, your program invokes *undefined behavior*.

Besides the above, expansion algorithms aren't complex, and explaining yours to your [rubber-duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) will help significantly before writing any code. In doing so, you'll see reallocating a pointer array with each new read is both costly and inefficient. A geometric expansion algorithms makes this much better. As a bonus, it fixes both of the problems above.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUFLEN  41
#define MAX_STR_FMT "%40s"

int main()
{
    char **tab = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, capacity = 0;

    char str[MAX_BUFLEN];

    while (scanf(MAX_STR_FMT, str) == 1 && strcmp(str, "END"))
    {
        // check for expansion 
        if (size == capacity)
        {
            size_t new_capacity = 2 * capacity + 1;
            void *tmp = realloc(tab, new_capacity * sizeof *tab);
            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                perror("Failed to expand dynamic table");
                break;
            }

            // save expanded table, and update capacity
            tab = tmp;
            capacity = new_capacity;
        }

        size_t slen = strlen(str)+1;
        if ((tab[size] = malloc(slen)) == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate buffer for new string");
            break;
        }

        // copy incoming string; update 'size' to reflect new count
        memcpy(tab[size++], str, slen);
    }

    //
    // TODO: use 'tab' holding 'size' pointers. 
    //

    // then free the table
    while (size-- > 0)
        free(tab[size]);
    free(tab);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Alternative: No pointers to pointers**

If your need truly requires fixed length allocations (as your code demonstrates), you don't need pointers to pointers *at all* (unless there is some hidden agenda for something like sorting where swapping pointers is *much* more efficient than swapping full string buffers).

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUFLEN  41
#define MAX_STR_FMT "%40s"

int main()
{
    char (*tab)[MAX_BUFLEN] = NULL; // see difference here
    size_t size = 0, capacity = 0;

    char str[MAX_BUFLEN];

    while (scanf(MAX_STR_FMT, str) == 1 && strcmp(str, "END"))
    {
        // check for expansion 
        if (size == capacity)
        {
            size_t new_capacity = 2 * capacity + 1;
            void *tmp = realloc(tab, new_capacity * sizeof *tab);
            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                perror("Failed to expand dynamic table");
                break;
            }

            // save expanded table, and update capacity
            tab = tmp;
            capacity = new_capacity;
        }

        // notice no additional allocations here
        strcpy(tab[size++], str);
    }

    //
    // TODO: use 'tab' holding 'size' strings. 
    //

    // then free the table
    free(tab);

    return 0;
}
```

**Summary**

Fixing your code was fairly simple, but making it better is too. Never stop thinking about *why* you're doing what your doing when crafting your algorithms, and spend plenty of time talk with your [rubber-duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line:

```
**tab=realloc(tab,(i+2)*sizeof(char*));
```

Here `**tab` dereferences `tab` to the first character in the first string stored in `tab`, which isn't what you want. Try this instead:

```
tab=realloc(tab,(i+2)*sizeof(char*));
```

If you turn on compiler warnings, they should catch this type of mistake.